# How to assign specific string value as type in dart

Tags: typescript, dart

Coming from typescript I was used to assign specific string values as types to class properties like so:

```
type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar';
class MyClass {
    myProp: MyType;

    // or even inline
    myProp2: 'foo2' | 'bar2';
}

const instance = new MyClass();

// I can do this:
instance.myProp = 'foo';

// Or this:
instance.myProp = 'bar';

// But I CANNOT do this:
instance.myProp = 'some_random_string_value';
```

How can I achieve the same in Dart?

Comment: Not possible in Dart. You can use `enum` to achieve a similar feature but not exactly the same: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart does not allow you to declare such a restriction.
What you can do instead is either to declare a proper enum:

```dart
enum MyType { foo, bar }
class MyClass {
    MyType myProp;
}
...
  myThing.myProp = MyType.foo;
```

or use strings, and then check that the value are among the valid ones:

```dart
String _checkMyType(String string, [String? argumentName]) {
  if (string == "foo" || string == "bar") return string;
  throw ArgumentError.value(string, argumentName, "Must be one of 'foo' or 'bar'");
}
class MyClass {
  String _myProp;
  String get myProp => _myProp;
  set myProp(String value) {
    _myProp = checkMyType(value);
  }
}
...
  myThing.myProp = "foo"; // Works
  myThing.myProp = "nah"; // Throws
```